# Proof using Mean Value Theorem: $f(a)=g(b), f(b)=g(a)$. Prove $f'(c)g'(c)\leq 0$

Tags: calculus

Can someone help me with this problem please?

Assume that the functions $f$ and $g$ are differentiable on $[a,b], f(a)=g(b)$ and $f(b)=g(a)$. Prove that there exists $c \in (a,b)$ so that $f'(c)g'(c) \leq 0$.

My work: Let $k(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. then $k(a)=f(a)-g(a)=f(a)-f(b)=g(b)-g(a)$, and $k(b)=f(b)-g(b)=f(b)-f(a)=g(a)-g(b)$.

By Mean Value Theorem, $ \frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}=g'(c_1)=  \frac{f(a)-f(b)}{b-a} $, and $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c_2)=  \frac{g(a)-g(b)}{b-a} $.

So, $g'(c_1)f'(c_2)=\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}\times-\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a} \leq 0$, since $b-a>0$ and something silmilarly to $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

Is this fine? I feel like it's not complete.. and do I have to say $c_1=c_2$?

Comment: Indeed it isn't complete for the reason you noticed. MVT does not guarantee you that the constants $c_{1,2}$ are the same. They are allowed to depend on the function the MVT is applied to.

Comment: oh noooooo what should I do now??

Comment: First of all things: Simplify your life. You can WLOG assume $[a,b] = [0,1]$ and $f(a) = 0, f(b) = 1$. (The latter requires a comment, can you figure it out?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $\phi(x) = f(x)+g(x)$.

It is clear that:
$$\phi(a) = \phi(b)$$

For the MVT, we have that there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that

$$ \frac{\phi(b)-\phi(a)}{b-a} = \phi'(c)$$

In this case:

$$\phi'(c) = 0 \Rightarrow f'(c) + g'(c) = 0 \Rightarrow f'(c) = -g'(c)$$

This means that:

$$f'(c)g'(c) = -[g'(c)]^2 \leq 0$$